# should javascript be deferred on page OR downloaded only if partial view is called on some button click?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

We have a partial view that gets loaded to the main page only if the user clicks on a button.

The partial view has few buttons, control etc. and we require javascript for all these actions that can be performed on that partial view.

We have two choices:

1. Include this javascript on page load as deferred: This won't affect page load time but would be unnecessarily downloaded even if user doesn't click on that button.
2. Download this javascript only when user clicks on that button: This may delay loading of that partial view a bit but would ensure that this javascript is downloaded only when its needed.

Which is better approach?

Comment: not sure if this is a question suited for SO, it is fairly opinion and scenario based... but ask yourself this: Will a majority of your users care about the extra data (i.e. are there a lot of mobile users)? Is it large enough that worrying about the unnecessary download is warranted? To an end user how will the application feel? Will loading it initially make the page more responsive? Will loading it with the partial view make the page feel sluggish?

Comment: There are a lot of mobile users. And since there are multiple partial views on the page, so unnecessary data download could be overkill.